# Hard to get my head around, generating average price for houses in each quadrant

Tags: data, geometry, intersection, spherical-geometry, circle

I'm able to determine the average price of houses sold in a particular area (like the squares on image below) dependent upon postcode. Although I can generate the average sale price for a particular postcode, I'm having difficulty utilizing these to the generations to the average house price for each quadrant. As in image.

Assuming I know the average house sale price for each of the letters noted on the image below, **how would you generate the average price for each colored quadrant?**

[image]

**Further information:**

1. The information contained within each quadrant (red, orange, green) should only impact that quadrant. (It's these values I hope to utilize to form an average for each separate quadrant)
2. These quadrants are intended to be eventually presented within Google Maps using circles (which I know how to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this being done in Arc or QGIS or something? What is the desired outcome?
Not sure about the vehicle you will use to represent your data, but it sounds like you want to make sure your averages are mutually exclusive to the quadrant that the data is coming from.
So, the red group (ABCD) needs to only consider those pieces of data to infer the average for that quadrant. NOT ABCDEFGHIJKL which would take into account all of your existing data.

Comment: I'll explain further above. 1 second.

Comment: Unless I am missing something I think the same method I described should be used. Only use the data from each quadrant to get the average for each quadrant. Avg = (A+B+C+D)/4 (or however many pieces of data are being used)

Comment: How many values would you suggest I attain to form this value for each quadrant? (I've used 4 above)

Comment: Well assuming the data is continuous, I would say as many pieces of data as you can manage. And if it is spatial data then more points for data that is more evenly spaced since objects in a close proximity tend to be more alike. That way the sample would be a better representation of the whole "quadrant" area. So it depends on the data you have.